# .NET Error: The dependency 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' could not be found

Tags: .net, excel, interop

My colleague has written a DLL which drives Excel.
When I reference his DLL in my .NET app, I get a warning:

```
The dependency 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' could not be found.
```

My app will compile.
However, when I get to the bit that uses my colleague's DLL to access Excel, an exception is thrown, with the message above.

We should have identical setups:  **Windows XP Pro SP3, VS2003, .NET 1.1, Office 2003**

My problem seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224181/net-microsoftofficeinteropexcel-and-interopexcel-dll), but I don't know if it's the same.

Any help or suggestions gratefully received!

### Update:

Thanks for answers so far!

I have not added an explicit reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.
Surely I shouldn't have to?
**However**:  When I tried to add this reference, I cannot find `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` in the Add Reference dialog.

Presumably this means that I am missing a DLL?
... But I don't understand how that could happen?!

### Update (fixed):

@ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells has the answer that fixed this for me: installing the Primary Interop Assemblies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may need to install the [Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302338.aspx) for Office, which can be downloaded from [Here.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)  Depending on the order that you install Visual Studio and Office they may not be installed by default.

Comment: If you're in Visual Studio 2010, you need to exit and re-enter before you'll see the Microsoft.Office.Interop.* dll files in the .NET tab when adding an assembly reference

Answer (score 3):

Have you explicitly added a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` in your project?

Comment: Really, nothing else we can say is of much value until this question is answered. Heh.

Comment: You should not add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  Instead ensure the PIA's are installed (see NXC's post) and add a COM reference to the  Microsoft Excel 11.0 Type Library.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your colleague to send you the Interop.Excel.dll file that he has in his bin folder. Alternatively as Jon has suggested above you can add a reference to Microsoft Excel library from the COM tab of the Add Reference dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to run the "official" F# samples on CodePlex.
Projects were referencing interop V11.
I removed the references and went to add them again, noticing I had V9, V12 and V14.
I added V12 and everything worked fine without any further changes.

Something you might want to try before installing yet another interop version.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it as follows:

- First I go to Add Reference
- Click COM on the top left part of Add Reference window.
- Find Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library.
- Or maybe it may not be 15.0, just object library.

I am using Microsoft Office 2013 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.