# Error on type conversion in Powershell EXCEL Com object

Tags: excel, powershell, reflection, enums

The following code:

```
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$constants = $xl.gettype().assembly.getexportedtypes() | GM

where-object {$_.IsEnum -and $_.name -eq 'constants'}

$pso = new-object psobject
[enum]::getNames($constants) | foreach { $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty $_ ($constants::$_) }
$xlConstants = $pso
```

Fails in the `[enum]::getNames` with the ff. message from Powershell 5.1 ISE:

```
Cannot convert argument "enumType", with value: "System.Object[]", for "GetNames" to type "System.Type": 
"Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Type"."
At line:9 char:1
```

Would be grateful for some guidance.

The code was copied from a 2010 answer to a post, which wanted to extract the Excel Enum constants.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extraneous `GM` (`Get-Member`) call in your code, and the `Where-Object` call - which should be where `GM` is - is disconnected from the pipeline above (which makes it a no-op).

`$constants` is therefore an *array* of objects (output by `Get-Member`), and passing an array to `[enum]::GetNames()` fails with the error you saw.

Find a corrected version of your code below, but y**our problem can be solved more simply**, combining the solutions from [the post your code came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272366/looking-up-the-value-for-ms-office-interop-constants-rather-than-hard-coding-the) **as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55325362/45375)**.

---

Here's a **corrected version of your code** that also shows you **a faster PSv5+ solution** for creating the custom object whose properties are named for the enumeration values' symbolic names and whose property values are the enumeration values themselves.

As the linked simpler solution shows, this isn't really necessary, however.

```
# Get the [enum]-derived type named 'Constants' from among
# the types that the Excel interop assembly exports.
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$constantsType = $xl.GetType().Assembly.GetExportedTypes() | 
  Where-Object { $_.IsEnum -and $_.Name -eq 'constants' }

# Construct a custom object that reflects the enum type's
# enumeration values as properties.
$xlConstants = New-Object pscustomobject
[enum]::GetNames($constantsType).ForEach({
  $xlConstants.psobject.properties.Add([psnoteproperty]::new($_, $constantsType::$_)) 
})
```

- If you'd rather use the raw `[int]` values as the property values, use `[psnoteproperty]::new($_, $constantsType::$_.value__)` instead.
- **`.psobject.properties` provides access to any object's properties, and the `.Add()` method allows creating properties**. `[psnoteproperty]::new()` creates a note property (shown as type `NoteProperty` by `Get-Member`), i.e., a property with a static value; the first argument is the property name, and the 2nd the property value, which can be of any type.

Comment: Sorry, am getting a new error message:<br/> Exception calling Getnames with "1" argument(s). "Value cannot be null<br>

Comment: @user8898465: As before, this implies that `$constantsType` contains `$null`, which in turn implies that the `$xl.GetType().Assembly.GetExportedTypes() | 
  Where-Object { $_.IsEnum -and $_.Name -eq 'constants' }` call unexpectedly did not find the `[enum]` type named `Constants` among Excel's exported types. It works for me, and without additional information it is impossible to diagnose your problem.